# How can I give a value to a Django environment variable from within the application itself?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, django-environ

I developed an application with its respective access login, when the user tries to log in, he must select a value that will be used throughout the execution of the application until the user closes the session.
I have my project configured with environment variables, I use the django-environ 0.8.1 library to configure these variables so that my application can access them in the .env file. How can I manage the login variable with these environment variables?

```
import environ

# environ init
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env.str('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', default = False)

# This is the variable that I need to change according to the option 
# that the user chooses when logging in
DATABASE_SAP_CHOSEN = 'SBOJOZF'
```

Comment: Settings are system wide, they are not user specific. You should take a look at [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use sessions.

My application requires the user select a client from a form selection once logged in, as each page is used to view/manipulate the clients data.

Example:

```
def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            request.session['client_id'] = client.objects.get(pk=request.POST['client_id'])
        return redirect(self.request.path)
```

Then when I want to call it in another view:

```
def get(self, request):
        selected_client = request.session.get('client_id')
        if selected_client == None:
           redirct(reverzelazy('client_selector'))
```

Comment: If I declare my session variable like this: 
`request.session['databaseSAP'] = database`
And I access it from other views like this: 
`database = request.session['databaseSAP']`
it is right? because it works for me, but I don't want something else to fail later

Comment: Honestly i didn't think that worked that's why I was using get, plus they use get in the django examples.